# Flutter Azure Face API

Tags: azure, flutter, dart, face-api

I'm tried to use Microsoft Azure Face API with Flutter and i'm using a library call [cognitive_face_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/cognitive_face_flutter#-example-tab-).

My code.

```
File img = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (img != null) {
      List<Face> _faces = await client.detect(
        image: img,
        returnFaceAttributes: FaceAttributeType.values,
        returnFaceLandmarks: true,
      );

      print('DETECTED FACES : ${_faces.length}');

      setState(() {
        _image = img;
        faces = _faces;
      });
    }
```

I got this Error : _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'String') on **await client.detect**

Does anyone know how to fix this? or have any library else i can use ?

Answer (score 1):

try to call that after setting the image state. like

```
if (_image != null) {
      _getImageSize(Image.file(_image, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth)).then((Size size) {
        print('CROPPED IMAGE WIDTH: ${size.width} HEIGHT: ${size.height}');
      });

      setState(() {
        image = _image;
        isLoading = true;
      });

      List<Face> _faces = await client.detect(
        image: _image,
        returnFaceAttributes: FaceAttributeType.values,
        returnFaceLandmarks: true,
      );

      print('DETECTED FACES: ${_faces.length}');

      setState(() {
        faces = _faces;
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }
```